# Create a new post using rest api and save featured image using an external image url

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, uploads, rest-api, media

I am trying to create a post using the rest API. Which I am able to do with a fetch request as below. `OurPostData` contains the title, content and **URL of a featured image** which is an external url

```
  fetch('https://mywebste.online/wp-json/wp/v2/post', {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'X-WP-Nonce': qrAjax.nonce
      }),
      body: JSON.stringify(OurPostData),
    }).then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      return response.json();
    }).then(data => console.log(data));
  });
```

This works except for the featured image. If I am able to do pass it to the callback function done using the below code may be I can achieve that?

```
add_action('wp_ajax_code_post_create', 'code_post_create_callback');
```

But I don't know how to pass it. The `data` in my code has the post id. ( How can I access it in `code_post_create_callback`?)

I can save the file using below

```
$file = 'https://externalwebsite.com/image.jpg';
      $file_array  = [ 'name' => wp_basename( $file ), 'tmp_name' => download_url( $file ) ];

      // If error storing temporarily, return the error.
        if ( is_wp_error( $file_array['tmp_name'] ) ) {
            return $file_array['tmp_name'];
        }

        // Do the validation and storage stuff.
        require_once ('wp-load.php');
        require_once ('wp-admin/includes/admin.php');
        $id = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, 0, $desc );
        //var_dump($id);
        // If error storing permanently, unlink.
        if ( is_wp_error( $id ) ) {
            @unlink( $file_array['tmp_name'] );
            return $id;
        }
```

How do I call `code_post_create_callback`? How do I access the `data` in this callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `wp_ajax_` (i.e. `admin-ajax.php`), how about [adding a custom REST API *field*](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/#adding-custom-fields-to-api-responses) and then using its `update_callback`, download the remote image and set it as the post featured image?

### Working Example

```php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'wpse_381217' );
function wpse_381217() {
    register_rest_field( 'post', 'featured_image_url', array(
        // If you don't want to expose the field in the REST API response, you
        // may ignore the get_callback, i.e. don't set it.
        'get_callback'    => function ( $post_arr ) {
            return get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post_arr['id'], 'full' );
        },

        'update_callback' => function ( $url, $post_obj ) {
            $file_array = array(
                'name'     => wp_basename( $url ),
                'tmp_name' => download_url( $url ),
            );

            if ( is_wp_error( $file_array['tmp_name'] ) ) {
                return false;
            }

            $id = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, 0 );

            if ( is_wp_error( $id ) ) {
                @unlink( $file_array['tmp_name'] );
                return false;
            }

            return set_post_thumbnail( $post_obj->ID, $id );
        },

        'schema'          => array(
            'description' => 'Featured image URL.',
            'type'        => 'string',
        ),
    ) );
}
```

Then, in your `OurPostData` variable, add the featured image URL with the name `featured_image_url`. E.g.

```js
const OurPostData = {
    title: 'testing featured_image_url',
    featured_image_url: 'https://example.com/image.png',
    // ...
};
```

Comment: That's an awesome idea. Thank you

Comment: Is there any callback function for fetch() like the jquery ajax , `data{ action : callbackfunction` ). Just learning new things I do really like the fetch for its similicity :)?

Comment: The `.then(data => console.log(data))` in your JS (in the question) is where you could run the callback, e.g. make another REST API request, e.g. uploading a file via the default [`/wp/v2/media` endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/media/#create-a-media-item) - `.then( data => { fetch( ... ); ... } )`. Or am I not understanding what you mean?

Comment: oh yes. I can call another request in there. Thanks again